# How can I find a number in a HTML document then use as NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsstring

In UIWebView, how can I find a number (there's no other numbers or text on the page, just one number in the centre) and then use that as an NSString to make a UILabel show that number?

**EDIT**: The code of the webpage (around the number):

```
<div style="width: auto; padding:0px; height: auto;" class="ajax_qe" id="ajax_qe_200139_1"><iframe id='qe_logFrm_200139'     
instance='1' class='frog3_enabled' style='display:none;'></iframe><div id="np_200139-1" class="brick s_php_eval" type="PHP"     
dfid=""></div><div id="np_200139-2" class="brick s_addspace" type="Blank Space" dfid=""><div style="overflow: hidden; font-size: 
0px; width: 100%; height: 5px; "></div></div><div id="np_200139-3" class="brick s_text" type="Text and Pictures" dfid=""><table 
border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width='100%' class='alt_200139'><tr><td><P align=center><STRONG><FONT color=#5dd228 
size=4>8</FONT></STRONG></P></td></tr></table></div><div class="page_marker" id="edit_link_200139_1" style="display: block; 
width:; height:;"><a class="edit_link rootpage" style="display: block;" href="#" onclick="qe_login(200139, 0); return false;" 
title="Edit this Page"><img src="/sysimages/editfullpage.gif" style="border: none;" /></a></div><div style="clear: both"></div>
</div><div id="r3603" style="position: relative;text-align: center;width: 100%;"><div style="z-index: 11;position: 
static;display: inline;">Powered by <a class=ROLLOVER href="http://www.frogteacher.com/" target=_blank><B>Frog</B></A></div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the HTML that you are parsing always stays the same (except your number, obviously) you could use something like this:

```
NSString* yourNumber;
NSScanner *htmlScanner =  [NSScanner scannerWithString:yourHtmlString];

[htmlScanner scanUpToString:@"<FONT color=#5dd228 size=4>" intoString:NULL];
[htmlScanner scanString:@"<FONT color=#5dd228 size=4>" intoString:NULL];

[htmlScanner scanUpToString:@"</FONT>" intoString:&yourNumber];
```

You can than parse the `yourNumber` however you like.

If, on the other hand, the HTML will differ significantly, I would use the [MWFeedParser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser) to parse, but this is a rather heavyweight solution.

Comment: I think this is unnecessary, as the OP could use `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` to walk the DOM tree... On second thought, maybe doing it your way is faster... Hmmm...

Comment: It's a good question and I honestly don't know which way is faster. I think it will heavily depend on the actual HTML.

Comment: The real performance hit with using JS is that it relies on WebKit's JSCore engine to run, which crosses all sorts of performance-heavy routines. But the OP **did** say that the HTML structure is static.

Comment: I'm building on the Frog (www.frogtrade.com) platform so wouldn't be able to use this method as I can't place specific HTML in specific places. Check back in a second though as my question should be updated with the source code :)

Comment: I don't know what you mean with 'I can't place specific HTML'. If you would be going for '<FONT color=#5dd228 size=4>' for the first and '</FONT>' for the second search, you should be good to go.

Comment: Don't worry, kind of hard to explain - and that should work. I'll try it and will reply back :-) thanks!

Comment: No problem. You should also give Jacob's method a shot to see which one is faster.

Comment: It says "Use of undeclared identifier 'yourHtmlString'"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4097/discussion-between-phlibbo-and-reddexuk)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
NSString *content = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML;"];

UILabel *label = ...;

[label setText:content];
```

Comment: @reddexuk Can you provide the exact HTML that you're using? (Update your question, please.)